# java for loop not producing expected result

Tags: java, for-loop

I would just like to ask about this for loop I did. I have a String named *content* with string value of ***"NameXesme esmeXMobileX2903489283482903X
NameXmer merXMobileX0697905967X"***.

My for loop is as follows:

```
for(int j = 0; j < content.length(); j++){
        if(Character.toString(content.charAt(j)).equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
            numberTxt.setText(content.charAt(j)+""+j); }
```

What expect to be seen in my numberTxt component (***JTextfield***) is "*N0*"(Nzero), but the output I'm seeing is "*N41*". I've done other codes that I know,

```
for(int j = 0; j < content.length(); j++){
    if(content.charAt(j) == 'N') numberTxt.setText(content.charAt(j)+""+j); }
```

but I still am not getting the right result. Am I doing things right? or did I miss something here?

Noticed the lack of *break* statement, did not have enough time to delete the question ahead.

Comment: a) please format your code properly, it is hard to read. b) If you want the *first* occurence of the letter `n` you most probably need a `break` within the `if`(don't forget the curly braces for the `if`-block if you do so). Right now, the loop will iterate over each character and the last occurence will be printed (actually, all occurences will be shown in the text field, but you will see only the last).

Answer (score 2):

Your String contains `N` multiple times.
If you want first occurence then `break` loop.
You can try this out :

```
for(int j = 0; j < content.length(); j++){
    if(content.charAt(j) == 'N'){
        numberTxt.setText(content.charAt(j)+""+j);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could use `indexOf` instead, then concatenate that with `N`